# Dart record pattern matching nullability deduction

Tags: dart, dart-pattern-matching

I would like to implement a method in Dart, something like the following:

```dart
int nullFirstCompare<T extends Comparable<T>>(T? a, T? b) {
  return switch ((a, b)) {
    (null, null) => 0,
    (null, _) => -1,
    (_, null) => 1,
    (final a, final b) => a.compareTo(b), // does not compile
  };
}
```

So, my hope would be that by the 4th case in the switch the Dart compiler would deduce that none of the record fields can be null. It does not, therefore the 4h case does not compile.

I wonder if this is a limitation or a bug in the compiler. Also if there is some elegant way to rewrite this code to make it work with the current Dart compiler.

```
% dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.0.6 (stable) (Tue Jul 11 18:49:07 2023 +0000) on "macos_arm64"
```

Other attempts so far:

```dart
int nullFirstCompare2<T extends Comparable<T>>(T? a, T? b) {
  return switch ((a, b)) { // error:  non_exhaustive_switch_expression
    (null, null) => 0,
    (null, _) => -1,
    (_, null) => 1,
    (final a?, final b?) => a.compareTo(b), 
  };
}

int nullFirstCompare3<T extends Comparable<T>>(T? a, T? b) {
  return switch ((a, b)) { 
    (null, null) => 0,
    (null, _) => -1,
    (_, null) => 1,
    (final a!, final b!) => a.compareTo(b), // warning: null_check_on_nullable_type_parameter
  };
}

int nullFirstCompare4<T extends Comparable<T>>(T? a, T? b) {
  return switch ((a, b)) { // error:  non_exhaustive_switch_expression
    (null, null) => 0,
    (null, _) => -1,
    (_, null) => 1,
    (T a, T b) => a.compareTo(b), 
  };
}
```

Also on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d09d69b3cd9e8e720ddc9a911b25f79f).

Thanks!

Marton

Comment: This sounds like a bug, but I can see it'd be very computationally expensive to recognize this upgrade.  Have you tried using `(final a?, final b?)` which promises to not match if they are possibly null, and then see if you get an exhaustive warning?  And if so, then try `(final a!, final b!)`.

Comment: Also try `(T a, T b)`... just a thought.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work, could be a bug. I suggest you open an issue [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues) so it can be seen by the people who develop the compiler.

Comment: For reference, it seems like the author of the question here have made the following issue to the Dart SDK: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53047

Comment: Thanks @julemand101 i was about to link it :)